# TS index types - compiler cannot resolve exact value when index type is used in interface

Tags: typescript

If I have the following function:

```
function test<T, K extends keyof T>(o: T, propertyValue: T[K], propertyName: K) {
    // ... do something
}
```

and I do:

```
interface Car {
    manufacturer: string;
    model: string;
    year: number;
}
let taxi: Car = {
    manufacturer: 'Toyota',
    model: 'Camry',
    year: 2014
};
test(taxi, 0, 'model');
```

compiler is able to detect that model property is not of type string so test invocation line fails. But If I try to use index type in interface like here:

```
export interface Change<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T> {
  timestamp: number;
  field: K;
  value: T[K];
}
const change: Change<Car> = {
  timestamp: 1484684700749,
  field: 'model',
  value: 0
};
```

It compiles fine. It allows you to set value to string or number even though actually property is specified by the field. Am I doing something wrong or perhaps that's not possible for cases like this due to the reason how compiler works?

You can see actual example [here in ts playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygHgCoBpEDSiKAHqmACZqIDWKAnnMItgHwAUcAXC-gA4AnOHxQCo9AGoBDADYgUPbAG0CAXX5CRY+gDkpAWwWEAlIgDeAKETXEAlFBACkABgDcFgL4WYYVAOBSECiIAMJSAuZWNvpSYCAB0I6iPBgCPgDm7jaI+nAUKDIpUGlgmVHW9CjhPHH6AEai7l4+fgnBIQAWsekoOPhEpORUtAxMLIgAvCOMzGyR2bCGGAZ8NSD1jeWIwDAFFDwEWTYAbrLyiiqqTRYWEAgYiBBdpUad3b1hAqyT8zaL6FAVjwAIwAFgAHKCAGyQgDszmcsNBAE5cFsdnseAByXL5GRYtHZU5yIzOTzuCwyezIKQkGA8T4-SzZGJxBIOOwCbHYOCMQEEra4grYsL6AT0AXZSrVRAAJmcYPJN1QGHYgLp+Gc+BxeQKWOMFKAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `K` can be *any* key of `T`, typescript cannot know which one.

Consider this example:

```js
const makeChange = (args: any): Change<Car> => {
  // some logic to return the change here.
}
```

What type should `Change<Car>` now use for `K`. As the `field`'s value is decided during runtime, you cannot assign a static type during compilation.

A way around this to define your `Change` type like this:

```js
interface Change<T, K extends keyof T> {
    timestamp: number;
    field: K;
    value: T[K];
}

const change: Change<Car, 'model'> = {
    timestamp: 1484684700749,
    field: 'model',
    value: 0 // not working as expected.
};
```

You need to specify the field (generic paramter `K`) in the type for the static type checking to work.

If you use the `Change` interface in other parts and do not work with a specific field, you can always add generic types to your function like this:

```js
const uploadChange = <K extends keyof Car>(change: Change<Car, K>) => {
 // ...
}
```

Comment: I understand all that but I am wondering how compiler is able to sort it out for my example with function?
```
function test<T, K extends keyof T>(o: T, propertyValue: T[K], propertyName: K) {
    // ... do something
}
test(taxi, 0, 'model'); // it detects that model property should be string and not number
```
if it can do it here, why it can't do it for the interface example. What is the difference there?

Comment: because with an interface you have a generic type, which cannot be resolved without any higher order reasoning and in the function call the `'model'` will be used as a narrow type which is known at compile time. With the interface the type declaration `let x: Type` is completly seperat and has to compile on its own without the variable initialization